# how to add glyphicon to bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to add a glyphicon to the left of a link in a dropdown menu, but cant seem to figure it out. This is what my code looks like:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">options
          <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">

          <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i><%=link_to "report link", report_path(report: {reportable_id: post.id, reportable_type: "Post"}), id: "report_#{post.class}_#{post.id}", class: "report_link", remote: true, method: :post %></li>
```

Can someone please explain to me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the icon inside the link - there's no visual downside to doing so, and even potentially improves UX (you can click on the icon too).

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i> link</a></li>
```

See this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/sWW7LiJMuL)

So your new ruby link would look like

```
<%=link_to "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-flag'></i> report link".html_safe, report_path(report: {reportable_id: post.id, reportable_type: "Post"}), id: "report_#{post.class}_#{post.id}", class: "report_link", remote: true, method: :post %>
```

(Apologies if this is wrong, I don't actually know Ruby. I assume this was a css positioning error, but if the Ruby is wrong too let me know and I shall delete this answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `span` outside of your `link_to`. You would remove the display text ("report link") after the `link_to` and add it back after the Glyphicon span class ends.

```
    <li>
      <%=link_to report_path(report: {reportable_id: post.id, reportable_type: "Post"}), id: "report_#{post.class}_#{post.id}", class: "report_link", remote: true, method: :post do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span> Report Link
      <% end %>
    </li>
```